# Is this going to create multiple threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method which is returning me a list of stock prices.

```
var tickers = Ticker.text.splice(',',' ');
var service = new StockService();
var tickerLoadingTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<StockePrice>>>();
foreach(var ticker in tickers)
{
   var loadTask = service.GetStockPriceFor(ticker,cancellationTokenSource.Token)
   tickerLoadingTasks.Add(loadTask);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tickerLoadingTasks);
// code for updating UI
```

I have above method which returns me list of stock price data. My confusion is that for each value in `tickers`, is new thread created or what?

`GetStockPrice` returns me Task of List of the stock prices for each stock.

Comment: `IEnmerable`? how did you get this code? Please use actual correct code.

Comment: There is no way to know from the code you've posted if a new thread is created. You'd need to look at the implementation for `GetStockPriceFor` (or maybe deeper) to see if it does.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: And, in reality if you have 1_000_000 tickers then your code can't possibly create 1_000_000 threads as each thread uses 1MB of RAM (at least) - so unless your machine has 1TB of RAM it couldn't run that way.

Comment: @Enigmativity what code does is parallel retrieves stock price. Do does it going to create new thread per ticker ?

Comment: @Coder We cannot know. It depends on _how_ those stock prices are retrieved.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see? Why are you asking random people on the internet if something **that you can test yourself** will happen?

Comment: @Coder - No, there's no certainty of that. You need to look at the implementation of the `GetStockPriceFor` to know. Nonetheless, there may only be a handful of threads actually used, and not one per ticker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `StockService` is an Http client, `GetStockPriceFor` will do an HTTP request. If the code is implemented correctly, the returned `Task` can be awaited to get the result of the HTTP call. While awaiting the `Task`, no thread is used.

The idea of async/await and I/O calls is that you can continue using the thread for something else while the operating system waits for the I/O call to finish. Once it's finished, a thread will be used to process the result of the I/O call.

Now remember, this is based upon the assumption you're doing an HTTP call.

This is a huge if since you don't show the actual implementation of the code. It could be that the code fetches the results synchronously and uses `Task.FromResult` to give you a `Task` that will immediately complete and not even switch threads.

Comment: yes, I am doing an HTTP call that returns me Task. And what I am doing is that I am calling HTTP method parallelly for each ticker.So what i know is that parallel programming uses multithreading so each request will be performed on a new thread asynchronously?

Comment: No it won't. As I explained, waiting for an I/O request does not require a thread. Instead, the current thread is returned to the threadpool where it can continu to do other things. Once the I/O request finishes, a thread is taken from the threadpool to run the remainder of your code.

Comment: what if these calls are made simultaneously? Does that going to create one thread per call ?

Comment: @Coder - No, it is never going to make one thread per call. There will be at a minimum 1 and a maximum a handful.